# a+= b faster than a = a+b. The logic behind the two operations

Tags: c++, operators

I was working on a leetcode problem to reverse a string such that such that if Input is `The boy is mad`, the output should be `mad is boy The`. I solved it but the solution seemed poor as I was running through the string a lot of times. On submitting the code, the time taken to compute all the test cases was ~250ms, and I believed it as I knew this was the worst possible code. I looked up one of the answers and ran that code, it ran in like 4ms. I wrote the same code again, but this time I used `a = a + b;` instead of `a += b;`, and the test cases again took around 250ms. So, I want to know what is the difference between these two and why does it take a long time on one when compared to the other.

PS - In my original (poor) code, on changing `a = a + b` to `a += b`, the code ran in like 8ms.

Here are the codes:
1. slow code(runtime - ~250 ms)

```
string reverseWords(string s) {
        if(s.length() == 0)
        {
            return s;
        }
        int itr = 0;
        // Remove white spaces from front
        while(s[itr] == ' ')
        {
            itr++;
        }
        s = s.substr(itr,s.length()-itr);
        if(s.length() == 0)
        {
            return s;
        }
        // Remover white spaces from back
        for(int i = s.length()-1; i>= 0 ;i--)
        {
            while(s[i] == ' ')
            {
                s = s.substr(0,i);
                i--;
                //cout << s << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        if(s.length() == 0)
        {
            return s;
        }
        cout << s << endl;

        // Remove more than one space in the middle
        for(int i = 0;i<s.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if(s[i] == ' ' && s[i+1] == ' ')
            {
                string temp;
                temp = s.substr(0,i);
                s = s.substr(i+1,s.length());
                s = temp + s;
                i--;
                //cout << s <<endl;
            }
        }
        string res = "";
        reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
        int start = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i <s.length();i++)
        {
            start = i;
            if(s[i] == ' ')
                continue;
            while(s[i] != ' ' && i < s.length())
            {
                i++;
                // cout << i << " ";
            }
            // cout << endl;
            string temp = s.substr(start,i-start);
            reverse(temp.begin(),temp.end());
            if(i != s.length())
                res = res + temp + " ";
            else 
                res = res + temp;
            //cout << temp << endl;
        }


        return res;
    }
```

2. Fast code(4ms)

```
string reverseWords(string s) 
{
    stack<string> elements;
    std::istringstream stream(s);
    std::string word;

    while (stream >> word)
    {
        elements.push(word);
    }

    string strReturn("");

    int stackSize = elements.size();
    int i = 0;
    while( !elements.empty())
    {
        i++;
        strReturn += elements.top();
        elements.pop();
        if( i != stackSize)
        {
            strReturn += " ";
        }
    }
    return strReturn;
}
```

3. Re written Fast code(250ms)

```
string reverseWords(string s) {
        // Check the first available Accepted solution to see the shitiest solution for the code

        stack<string> availableWords;
        istringstream stream(s);
        string word;

        while(stream >> word)
        {
            availableWords.push(word);
        }

        int len = availableWords.size();
        string res = "";
        int i = 0;
        while(!availableWords.empty())
        {
            res += availableWords.top();
            availableWords.pop();
            i++;
            if(i != len)
            {
                res += " ";
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: For a debug build there *might* be a difference, but who cares? For a release build with optimizations enabled, there's unlikely to be *any* difference.

Comment: We do not know what options leetcode uses for their compiler.

Comment: If we talk about`operator+(std::string, std::string)` then it will create a new temporary and move that to the old string. This will result in an extra allocation, 2 copies and one deallocation. `operator+=` on the other hand is in-place and thus will try to resize the already allocated space if its not enough and only results in a single copy.

Comment: Strings with all optimizations ain't that easy optimized, I wouldn't be surprised to see a difference. Allocating memory, storing it in a union, reading it out ...

Comment: The expression `a = a + b` creates a temporary `std::string` to store the result of `a + b`, which is then stored in `a` (which releases content of the original `a` and then copies the temporary to it). The expression `a += b`, if appropriately implemented, does not create a temporary `std::string`. It's more complicated than that, since compiler optimisation & elision of temporaries in different C++ standards may be in play, but - particularly if you compile without optimisation - the difference associated with creating and copying temporaries and then releasing them can explain what you see.

Comment: please include compiler version, options and the benchmark you used. details do matter

Comment: At the ones arguing about "temporaries" etc. -- this ain't 1998. Move operations are a thing, for one. Make sure what you're saying here is what actually happens, and not what you *think* happens. And if you've made sure, write *answers*, not comments. Comments are for improving questions.

Comment: The responses about "temporaries" -- that may be valid if the compiler is running an unoptimized build.  But as mentioned by @DevSolar, this is no longer 1998 or even early 2000's.  An optimizing compiler can do amazing things these days, and I don't know if Leetcode is turning on the optimizations when C++ code is submitted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Sure, it is no longer 1998.   However, the OP specified nothing about the (age of) the compiler or optimisation settings and the difference being observed is consistent with what happens with temporary objects without elision or move operations in play.  Not everyone has the privilege of using or being able to update to a recent compiler.   Much as some people here like to harp on about any mention of C++ standards before C++17, practically there is still scope for older concepts to be relevant to posted problems.

Comment: Leetcode uses `g++` (8.2) `-std=c++17` but it doesn't say anything about optimization.

Comment: @Peter: Move operations are nine years old now. I do understand that not everyone can update, heck, I am in that position myself. But **please**, let us not drop word on temporaries etc. in half-answers, blaming the language for our individual dusty infrastructure. Post **answers**, and explain the difference between debug and release, unoptimized and optimized, old standard and new. The comments above aren't helping anything or anybody.

Comment: @DevSolar See for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/ybKSDo. Notice the subtle differences in generated asm. Especially the call to the move-assignment which is not inlined, which btw does alot of work (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h). Nevermind that I actually mentioned move semantics (which are no magic potion). And while most compilers do pretty good at optimizing they are no omniscient beings which output perfect code in all situations. Optimizations are not guaranteed in any way.

Comment: A prime example btw are most `std::tuple` implementations vs `boost::fusion::vector` with regards to memory layout and alignment requirements

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: You are missing the point. **Write answers, not comments.** Comments cannot be voted, edited, accepted...

Comment: Unless the ISO standard actually *mandates* the use of temporaries, you *cannot* assume anything about them. I haven't looked but I'd be surprised if it did. The standards are all about observable behaviour (hence the "as if" rule), not implementation details.